# Referencing attributes with insert triggers

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I have two relations I am working with Highschooler(ID, name, grade) and likes(ID1, ID2)

I want to make a insert trigger that inserts records into the likes relation.

When I insert a new Highschooler in the Highschooler relation I want my insert trigger to insert records into likes and basically the new highschooler likes everyone in the same grade.

What I want is like something below:

```
create trigger R1
after insert on Highschooler
for each row
when (Old.grade = New.grade)
begin
    insert into Likes values(New.ID, Old.ID));   
end;
```

however, with insert triggers the Old reference is not valid! so how can I reference the old attributes?

@Bill Gregg: Thanks for the tip and the explanation. So is this what you are suggesting?

```
create trigger R1
after insert on Highschooler
for each row
begin
    insert into Likes values(hs.ID, old.ID));
    select(hs.ID, old.ID from Highschooler hs, Highschooler old
    where hs.grade = old.grade and hs.ID <> old.ID
end;
```

I ran it on my DBMS and it is not executing. I suspect that there is some issue with having the select statement after the insert.

Comment: I am using sqlite by the way.

Comment: You can't mix your insert methods.  You can't "insert values" and "insert select".  I think my code will work as written (assuming that you put it into your "for each row" action, and that is in fact valid SqlLite syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Old" on an insert trigger, because the old row didn't exist.  You are only inserting a new row.

I think what you want is

```
for each row

insert into Likes (FirstID,SecondID)
select hs.id, new.id
from HighShooler hs
where hs.grade = new.grade
and hs.id != new.id
```

Comment: wouldn't you need a join between two highschooler relations?
Highschooler hs, Highschooler old?

Comment: You are getting the new highschooler in your for each row.